# Он обречён быть счастливым

Tags: синонимы

Есть ли слово, являющееся синонимом к "обречённый", но с позитивной смысловой окраской?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выражение *обречен на успех* давно уже стало привычным фразеологизмом.

Мы же не устанем соединять: новый литературный язык ― новая историография; живой язык письма ― существенная причина того, что **Карамзин был обречен на успех!** (Н. Эйдельман, *Последний летописец*)

Возможный "синоним" с положительным значением, но из  другой грамматической категории: *суждено*. Хотя чаще всего он употребляется в известной мрачной поговорке (*кому суждено быть повешенным, тот не утонет*), ничто не мешает нам вставить позитив:

Вам же **суждено быть добрым гением** по отношению ко мне и семейству моему. (П. В. Анненков, *Письма к Тургеневу*)